# Digital to Analog conversion in Multisim

Tags: adc, dac, multisim

Here is schematic for Analog to Digital conversion:

[image]

Here are two Digital to Analog converters in Multisim:

[image]

Which one should I use? I want to connect it at output of ADC to get original sine wave. How should I connect it (which pins should I use)?

EDIT: 
I found answer, however, other problem occurs :)
Here is schematic with 8bit DAC:

[image]

Here is transient analysis, showing input and output sine wave:

[image]

What are voltage spikes at output signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your ADC is only 8 bits, and the DACs you show are 16 bits, I'd say neither - look for an 8 bit DAC (although you could use the 16 bit parts, and tie the lowest 8 bits to ground).

Read the datasheets for those parts (or any other you might find) to find the features of each, and how to use them.